# Sngrep Unknown File Format Error

Tags: networking, macos, file-format, pcap

I am attempting to use the sngrep utility on a Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.4 and getting an error when I try to open any pcap file.

The error is as follows:

Johns-MacBook-Pro:Downloads gojira$ sngrep -I 12345.pcap 
Couldn't open pcap file 12345.pcap: unknown file format

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get this to work properly? I have been able to open other pcap files before without this issue.

Comment: What does the command `file 12345.pcap` print?

Comment: 12345.pcap: gzip compressed data, from Unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a *gzipped* (compressed) pcap file, or possibly a gzipped pcapng file.  Wireshark/TShark can read those files, but programs such as sngrep, which use libpcap/WinPcap, can't do so unless they do the uncompression themselves, and sngrep doesn't.

Rename it to 12345.pcap.gz, and then do `gunzip 12345.pcap.gz`; that'll uncompress it into a file named 12345.pcap, which will probably be a pcap or pcapng file, either of which OS X 10.11.4's libpcap can read.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting problem. I'm going to write a shell script since I want to use sngrep more often and need to look at pcaps that happen to be compressed like this.